# How to display invoice items from one DataGridView (Invoice) to another DataGridView (Items) c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview, textbox

I'm using VS and SQL Server. I have problem with query:

`SELECT *
FROM dbo.ul_dok
WHERE (dok_id_fk = @dok_id_fk)`

When I run query in SQL Server, everything is working great, window pops to ask me for dok_id_fk, and I insert it manually.

I have entered this code in c#:

```
conn.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("select ul_dok_id, ul_dok_dat, dok_id_fk, fil_model_no_fk, kol_ul_dok " +
            " from ul_dok where dok_id_fk = @dok_id_fk", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dok_id_fk", txt_Dokument.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        grb_Stavke_Dok.Show();

 conn.Close();
```

Everything else is working, I just can't show product items of the invoice document.

Have set on Invoice DataGridView that when I click on cell to load ID of the invoice to TextBox (txt_Dokument), and then re-use it in the query that is listing products with the same Invoice ID.

If this isn't enough info, pls tell me to provide more. At the moment I cant be more specific about my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a solution to my problem, and here is the code.

```
private void DisplayData_Sa_istom_Sifrom()
    {

        conn.Open();
        DataTable dt_Stavke = new DataTable();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select ul_dok_dat as [Datum], fil_model_no_fk as [Oznaka filtera], kol_ul_dok as [Kolicina] " +
            " from ul_dok where dok_id_fk = @dok_id_fk", conn);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dok_id_fk", txt_Dokument.Text);
        da.SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        da.Fill(dt_Stavke);
        dgv_stavke.DataSource = dt_Stavke;

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a `SELECT` operation and calling `ExecuteNonQuery()` ... that's wrong cause that will return you only the number of rows affected and not the result set you expected. Rather you should call `ExecuteReader()` like

```
cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: I try with ExecuteReader and nothing happen. I changed my code, and now I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". When I click on Inv_docDGV the Inv_doc_ID is shown in the txt, after that I want to show only items with that ID.
Here is the other code:
`conn.Open();
DataTable dt_Stavke = new DataTable();
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * " + " from ul_dok where dok_id_fk = @dok_id_fk", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dok_id_fk", txt_Dokument.Text);
da.Fill(dt_Stavke);
da.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
dgv_stavke.DataSource = dt_Stavke;
conn.Close();`